# List to data.frame in r

Tags: r, performance, list, dataframe

Is there any better way to transform a huge list(more than 100k) to a data.frame.

```
for (i in 1:length(google_20180623_list)) {

    if (google_20180623_list[[i]]$status != "OK") next

    name <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$name
    formatted_address <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$formatted_address
    place_id <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$place_id
    geom <- data.frame(google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$geometry$location)
    types <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$types
    types <- paste(types, collapse = "/")

    oa <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$opening_hours$weekday_text
    if (is.null(oa)){
        oa <- NA

    } else {
        oa <- as.data.frame(oa)
        oa <- oa %>% separate(oa,into=c("days", "opening"), sep=": ", remove=T)
        oa <- oa %>% spread(key = "days", value = "opening")
    }      
    rating <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$rating
    if (is.null(rating)) {rating<-NA}

    price_level <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$price_level
    if (is.null(price_level)) {price_level<-NA}

    phone <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$international_phone_number
    if (is.null(phone)) {phone<-NA}

    website <- google_20180623_list[[i]]$result$website
    if (is.null(website)) {website<-NA}
    cb<-cbind(place_id
                ,name
                ,formatted_address
                ,geom
                ,phone
                ,website
                ,rating
                ,price_level
                ,oa
                ,types
      )

    google_20180623_list_unlist<-rbindlist(list(google_20180623_list_unlist,cb),fill = T)

}
```

This code is incredible slow,it takes more than 24 hours. Any idea?

The data is from google place details api.

Thx for your help.

Comment: show a snippet of the list, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing that task in another programming language would be far more efficient.  Try to convert that into a file and then read it with R.